# Why Iterator<E> iterator() is put in Collection, AbstractCollection when already in Iterable

Tags: java, collections, iterable

When Iterator `iterator()` is put in `Iterable` interface and this is extended by `Collection` interface and `AbstractCollection` interface, why this is again mentioned in `Collection`/`AbstractCollection` as no definition is given for this in abstract class.

Please help me to understand what I am missing in this from design perspective

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `iterator()` appears in Iterator and Collection as the Javadoc is different.  In AbstractCollection it is different again, but doesn't appear to add much value.

Comment: This explains nothing.

Comment: @EJP I am sure you understand how javadoc works and you have to redeclare a method in a sub class or interface if you want to give it a different javadoc even if without the javadoc it would be redundant.

Comment: @PeterLawrey can you please elaborate on :  "you understand how javadoc works" as I don't understand what do you mean by this statement

Comment: @Naroji To override a Javadoc of a method in a sub-class, you have to declare the method again.  Without considering the Javadoc, this re-declaration would be redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Well Iterable is since 1.5 whereas Iterator and Collection are since 1.2.
Not sure why AbstractCollection defines it again though, it's javadoc is slightly different though.